# Logstash output to elasticsearch - how to include external synonyms file?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

Elasticsearch newbie here...

I am using Logstash to output a big CSV file inside an ElasticSearch index and I need to include a SOLR synonyms external file (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) into account when indexing.

I see that when the index is done directly from ElasticSeaarch Indices API , this operation can be done by specifying the synonym file path in the index configuration JSON, something like :

```
"custom_synonym": {
"type": "synonym",
"synonyms_path": "analysis/synonyms.txt"
}
```

But I can't find anywhere how can I include the same file from the logstash config file when indexing from Logstash

I searched in official documentation, but I can't find any useful hint :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.3/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you set the index setting/mapping beforehand and then use logstash to index your document. The synonym file path is relative to the config directory of Elasticsearch installation

Comment: Hi, actually I'm mapping / configuring the CSV file directly in logstash .config file by using a filter { csv {....  } } directive where i specify separator, columns , mutate etc. so I am actually bypassing the elastic search config.

That's what I learned from various tutorials and it is working flawlessly :)  Do you mean there is a way to include an elasticsearch config JSON to be parsed during logstash processing ?

Comment: Check out index templates and how to use them